# Write formatted text in pug mixin attributes

Tags: pug

I need to write multiline text in mixin attribute. But can't find right way to do this.

All this methods doesn't work:

```
+someMixin({
  key: "text in \n two lines"
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: "text in&ensp;two lines"
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in${&ensp;}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in#{&ensp;}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in${\n}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in#{\n}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in#{br}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in${br}two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: `text in<br/>two lines`
})
```

```
+someMixin({
  key: 'text in<br/>two lines'
})
```

Tell me please about possibility to do this and about right way.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at using a [mixin block](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks) for this content instead of mixin arguments?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't pass for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug mixins were designed to take attributes for control variables and blocks for content.  You're trying to use attributes for content, which is why you're finding it so difficult to accomplish this.

This mixin will treat the key as a delimited string, splits it into an array, then outputs `<p>` elements for each member in the array.

```
mixin someMixin(options)
  - var delimiter = '\n';
  - var output = options.key.split(delimiter);
  each line in output
    p= line
```

So this

```
+someMixin({
  key: "text in \n two lines \n no wait make it three"
})
```

Will then output this:

```
<p>text in </p>
<p> two lines <p>
<p> no wait make it three</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm already doing something like your code. I was just looked for more elegant opportunity to do this.